# Laravel layout keep the nav link with different background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am making a dashboard. It has a layout included in all the dashboard pages and it contains links. I need to specify the active page link with different background.

I wrote the code below to do this, but when I click on a link it reloads the page to go to the requested page and layout is refreshed and everything returns to default.

What is the easiest way to handle this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidebar-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sidebar-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #9E852D;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.exit-dashboard {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 610px;
  background-color: #B79B3A;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 9999999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/40a844b83b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@yield('styles')

<div class="exit-dashboard d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="a-reset">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-img text-center pt-5">
      <img src="{{ asset('images/location-hover-icon.png') }}" class="w-50">
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-links pt-5">
      <div class="row flex-column">
        <a href="#" class="a-reset">
          <a href="{{ route('dashboard.newcairo.interests') }}" class="a-reset">
            <div class="sidebar-link py-2">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope px-2"></i>
              <h6 class="nexa-bold text-white d-inline-block">iCity New Cairo</h6>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="{{ route('dashboard.october.interests') }}" class="a-reset">
            <div class="sidebar-link py-2">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope px-2"></i>
              <h6 class="nexa-bold text-white d-inline-block">iCity October</h6>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="{{ route('dashboard.october.chillout.interests') }}" class="a-reset">
            <div class="sidebar-link py-2">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope px-2"></i>
              <h6 class="nexa-bold text-white d-inline-block">Chillout October</h6>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="{{ route('dashboard.rashikma.interests') }}" class="a-reset">
            <div class="sidebar-link py-2">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope px-2"></i>
              <h6 class="nexa-bold text-white d-inline-block">Ras El Hikma</h6>
            </div>
          </a>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main p-5">
    <h3 class="text-white nexa-bold pb-4">@yield('tab-title')</h3>
    <div>
      @yield('content')
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/dashboard_layout.js') }}"></script>
@yield('scripts')
```

Comment: The issue is because clicking the link causes the current page to be unloaded (with the class you just set) and the new page to be loaded (in a default state without the class). You either need to 1) set the active page class server side, so that it's present in the DOM when the page loads, or 2) convert your entire site to an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) so that all content is dynamically loaded and you never reload the page. The former is by far the easier to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Route** facade to check the active route. It will check if the active route is the same, and will return true or false, using which we can make a ternary condition.

```php
<a href="#" class="a-reset">
    <a href="{{ route('dashboard.newcairo.interests') }}" class="a-reset">
        <div class="{{Route::is('dashboard.newcairo.interests') ? 'active' : 'sidebar-link'}} py-2">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope px-2"></i>
            <h6 class="nexa-bold text-white d-inline-block">iCity New Cairo</h6>
        </div>
    </a>
</a>
```